# How to remove inside array complete based on id?

Tags: javascript

I have array like this

```
var curChanges = [
                   {id:1, isChecked:true},
                   {id:2, isChecked:false},
                   {id:3, isChecked:true}
                 ];
```

Now, if i want to remove second array i.e {id:2, isChecked:false} dynamically, How do i do?
Here id is unique.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That can't exist. you can't use the `=` sign inside of objects. it would have to be `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have a syntax error. Object property values are set with `:`, not with `=`:

```
var curChanges = [
    {
        id: 1,
        isChecked: true
    },
    // etc...
];
```

Assuming the order of elements in the array is not fixed, the easiest way to achieve what you're trying to do will be to use the ES5 `Array.prototype.filter` method:

```
curChanges.filter(function (elem) {
    return elem.id !== 2;
});
```

If you return `true` from the filter function, the element will stay in the array. If you return `false`, it will be removed.

Comment: Just to clarify, you would have to do `curChanges = curChanges.filter(function` because it returns a new array and does not modify the existing one.

Comment: +1 because correct. An exmaple function ´removeElementWithId´ would be nice, but all in all sound. :)

Answer (score 0):

first off, invalid array. Should be `:` not `=`

so it becomes:

```
var curChanges = [ {id:1, isChecked:true}, {id:2, isChecked:false}, {id:3, isChecked:true}];
```

Use a filter to remove based on id:

```
curChanges.filter(function(i) { return i.id!=2;})
```

Or to directly remove the second element :

```
curChanges.splice(1,1);
```